# Invalid Argument Error while training in Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I am trying to make a movie recommendation model using keras:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import keras
from keras.layers import Input, Embedding, Dot, Flatten

rating = pd.read_csv("./ratings.csv",usecols=[0,1,2])
users = len(rating.userId.unique())
movies = len(rating.movieId.unique())
embed_size = 3
train, test = train_test_split(rating, test_size=0.2)

movie_input = Input(shape=[1], name="movie_in")
movie_embed = Embedding(movies, embed_size, name="movie_embed")(movie_input)
movie_vector = Flatten(name="flatten_movies")(movie_embed)

user_input = Input(shape=[1], name="user_in")
user_embed = Embedding(users, embed_size, name="user_embed")(user_input)
user_vector = Flatten(name="flatten_users")(user_embed)

prod = Dot(axes=-1, name="dot-product")([movie_vector, user_vector])

model = keras.Model(inputs=[user_input, movie_input], outputs=prod)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
model.fit(x=[train.userId, train.movieId], y=train.rating,epochs=10, 
verbose=0)
```

When I try to train the model I am getting the following error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: 
indices[15,0]= 7438 is not in [0, 5000)

[[{{node movie_embed/embedding_lookup}} = GatherV2[Taxis=DT_INT32, 
Tindices=DT_INT32, Tparams=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@training/Adam/Assign_2"], 
_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"] 
(movie_embed/embeddings/read, movie_embed/Cast, 
training/Adam/gradients/movie_embed/embedding_lookup_grad/concat/axis)]]
```

But most of the online tutorials use the same code, it works properly for them.

Answer (score 0):

Your `movie_embed` embedding layer (basically a lookup table) has 5000 rows, so it expects integers between 0 and 5000 as input. You are giving it 7438 as input, which causes the error. There are probably 5000 unique values in `rating.movieId`, but apparently also values outside of the interval `[0, 5000)`. You'll need to map your `train.userId` integers onto this interval to make it work.

Comment: Note that indices are zero-based, so it expects values between 0 and 4999 (inclusive), not up to 5000.